# Как застилизовать input [time]?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Как застилизовать input [time]?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с помощью таблиц стилей .css по классу или тегу, id мб. через .js можно.

Answer (score 2):

```css
input[type=time] {
  border: none;
  color: #2a2c2d;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  width: 180px;
}

input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
  padding: 19px 4px;
}

/*Час*/
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  border-radius: 15%;
  padding: 19px 13px;
  color: black;
}

/*Минуты*/
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 15%;
  padding: 19px 13px;
  color: black;
}

/*Секунды*/
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 15%;
  padding: 19px 13px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="time">
```